# I need to find out the result matching between the specific time,Except date in mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5754f6b904896f7e0c8b45e5"),
"coordinates" : [
    76.7033471,
    30.7104586
],
"delivery_delay" : NumberLong(0),
"delivery_radius_in_km" : 10,
"delivery_slot_duration" : NumberLong(30),
"description" : "wgwhsh",
"image" : "item_5751680404896f7e0c8b45dd_15755.png",
"image_thumbnail" : "item_5751680404896f7e0c8b45dd_15755.png",
"item_id" : "5751680404896f7e0c8b45dd",
"pick_up_or_delivery" : "Delivery",
"price_in_primary_currency" : 300,
"primary_currency" : "INR",
"quantity_available" : NumberLong(6),
"quantity_delivered" : NumberLong(10),
"quantity_ordered" : NumberLong(100),
"recurring" : true,
"repeat_every_friday" : true,
"repeat_every_monday" : true,
"repeat_every_saturday" : true,
"repeat_every_sunday" : true,
"repeat_every_thursday" : true,
"repeat_every_tuesday" : true,
"repeat_every_wednesday" : true,
"restriction" : [
    "Vegetarian",
    "Beef free"
],
"sale_event_latitude" : "30.7104586",
"sale_event_longitude" : "76.7033471",
"seller_address_id" : "5751142604896f7e0c8b45c8",
"seller_designation_as_shown_to_buyers" : "good selle",
"seller_rating" : 4,
"seller_user_id" : "575110eb04896f7e0c8b45bf",
"title" : "anamak",
"type" : [
    "Indian"
],
"pickup_date_delivery_and_time_from" : ISODate("2016-06-06T04:05:54Z"),
"pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to" : ISODate("2016-06-14T04:06:54Z"),
"cut_off_time" : ISODate("2016-06-10T04:06:54Z"),
"status" : true,
"updated_at" : ISODate("2016-06-06T04:06:17.017Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2016-06-06T04:06:17.017Z")
```

}

I have a collection with above record ,there are two date object:

`1->pickup_date_delivery_and_time_from`

`2->pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to`

Above fields are stored with `timestamps` .Now i want to make a query for get all result where `"pickup_date_delivery_and_time_from(only time)"` is less than `04:05:14Z` and `"pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to(only time)"` should be greater than `04:05:14Z` leave the date from above fields.

Only time should be  taken in concern.

I have to match above fields  with current time.

Any help!!!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i have tried so far getting hour ,minute and seconds from both of the dates and tried to match them with current time hour,minute and seconds.

Comment: `Above fields are stored with timestamps`, so fields are already including `datetime`. So query you can't do just using time, as you have mentioned in your question. You need to use date as well

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to maintain a separate time field along with the date to get the best performance.

If you cannot change the schema and if you are bound to use what you have, there are two approaches.

1. Use `$where`

`db.mycollection.find({$where : function() { return <your matching criteria>} })`

Last resort. This would give a performance hit.

2. Use aggregation

   `{ "_id" : 1, ISODate("2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z") }
   db.mycollection.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $project:
            {
              year: { $year: "$date" },
              month: { $month: "$date" },
              day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
              hour: { $hour: "$date" },
              minutes: { $minute: "$date" },
              seconds: { $second: "$date" },
              milliseconds: { $millisecond: "$date" },
              dayOfYear: { $dayOfYear: "$date" },
              dayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: "$date" },
              week: { $week: "$date" }
            }
        }
      ]
   )`

and use other pipeline operators to match according to your need.

check out
[$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) and
[aggregation with date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/)

Comment: its a search functionality am using the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
"start_year"                            =>  array('$year'=>array('$pickup_date_delivery_and_time_from')),
                                                    "start_hour"                            =>  array('$hour'=>array('$pickup_date_delivery_and_time_from')),
                                                    "start_minute"                          =>  array('$minute'=>array('$pickup_date_delivery_and_time_from')),
                                                    "start_second"                          =>  array('$second'=>array('$pickup_date_delivery_and_time_from')),
                                                    "end_year"                              =>  array('$year'=>array('$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to')),
                                                    "end_hour"                              =>  array('$hour'=>array('$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to')),
                                                    "end_minute"                            =>  array('$minute'=>array('$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to')),
                                                    "end_second"                            =>  array('$second'=>array('$pickup_delivery_date_and_time_to')),
```

I have take out start min ,start hour and start sec from both of the date but no luck to identify that the time i am going to be provide will match with 100% accuracy.

I found solution what i have done ---->>>>>>>

I got the hour from the time using mongo $hour and minute using $minute and same second .I added all of the seconds and also do the same from date which has to be matched .Now i compare seconds of input from the total seconds of date saved in database.

Because seconds are starting from 0 at 12:00 on the current night.

Comment: if i have to match 04:05:14 then am matching first hour .that will be ok ,But what about min and second, any suggestion please